# How to solve the curl certificate issue on MAC OS on Laravel installation?

Tags: php, macos, laravel, curl, composer-php

While installing Laravel

```
$ composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Getting this error

```
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: no valid certs found cafile stream: `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem'
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
```

**UPDATE**:

Also the command `composer self-update` throws the following error

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                               
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: no valid certs found cafile stream: `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.  
  pem'                                                                                                                                   
  Failed to enable crypto                                                                                                                
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I am using XAMPP5.6.3 (xampp-osx-5.6.3-0-installer) with OSX 10.9.5

I downloaded the certificate from curl but not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue solved:

1) Download the certificate file like (It is important to download using wget because copy paste the html file was not working for me)

```
$ brew install wget
wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

2) Copy the file and paste to the following directory (Make sure the read write permission is there)

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/cacert.pem
```

3)Add the following line to php.ini

```
openssl.cafile=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/cacert.pem
```

4) Restart the Apache

5) Running the command `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"` will install the Larvel.

Answer (score 3):

On Macosx curl is fine to download safely in cacert.pem :

```
echo "Downloading cacert.pem..."
curl -sSL http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem >> cacert.pem
mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
mv -v cacert.pem /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
```

More about CA file bootstrapping

```
brew info openssl
```